# How to display label and values of a StackedBar in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How can I display the label and value of a Stack in a stacked bar graph generated by [MpAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library similar to the regular bar graph shown below?

I seem to only have access to value of X and Y but not the individual Stack's label. I am looking for the individual label of the Stack itself. Entry and Highlight in `onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h)` both don't seem to have this data.

[image: Non Stacked Bar graph]

Comment: `only have access to value of X and Y but not the individual Stack's label` means ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya X and Y axis values. Suppose X is `Day 1`, `Day 2`, `Day 3`, etc. and Y is some number like 30, 50, 20. One bar for `Day 1` with Y value may contain stacks like `A-10`, `B-5`, and `C-15`. I have access to `Day 1` and value 10, 5, and 15 but not `A-10`, `B-5`, and `C-15`.

Comment: Can you just show your code ?

Comment: My code is exactly same as the sample. https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/StackedBarActivity.java